# excel if statement error words + formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Excel is giving me an error for the third part of my if statement:

```
=IF(B37>=(2*B36),(C37/(B37/B36)),"take from tube 1" (C37/(B37/B35))
```

It seems to dislike the combination of words plus a formula. What can I do to have it read correctly?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? It seems like your either missing a , or you're missing a (). But it all depends on what you want to do.

Comment: "It seems to dislike the combination of words plus a formula"--that's because there's no operator or function to tell it what to do...  Are you trying to output a string that is "take from tube 1x",where x is the result of the calculation?  If so, you need an & in between.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(B37>=(B36*2),(C37/(B37/B36)),"take from tube 1" & (C37/(B37/B35)))`

As Madball said you need an `&` operator if your trying to output a string and the result of the sum at the end. Was also missing a close bracket from the end.